# Is it possible that two neutrons can merge?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrons, binding-energy, neutron-stars

At the center of neutron stars are tightly packed neutrons with almost no space between them. Also, proton and electron have all merged (*electron capture*) forming as much neutrons as possible. When this star exceeds the *Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff limit*, the result would be a black hole.

Out of curiosity, if neutrons in extreme sense could ever merge or undergo a $n+n$ reaction?

Comment: What would be the output of an n-n reaction?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexaquark

Comment: The discussion of the dineutron [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutronium#Neutronium_and_the_periodic_table) may be of use: it has been observed, but is a transient resonance rather than a bound state.

Comment: $n + n \rightarrow e + p + \bar{\nu}_e$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The existence of [quark stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_star) has been considered. These are hypothesized to be more dense than neutron stars and to consist of [quark-gluon plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma). In such a plasma the boundaries between nucleons would no longer exist. Many open questions exist about quark matter, but the existence quark-gluon plasma is considered to be confirmed.
[image]

Comment: I thought the existence of QGPs (but not quark stars) was pretty well-established experimentally by now?

Comment: You are correct. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutronium#Neutronium_and_the_periodic_table):

> The dineutron, containing two neutrons, was unambiguously observed in
> 2012 in the decay of beryllium-16.[8][9] It is not a bound particle,
> but had been proposed as an extremely short-lived resonance state
> produced by nuclear reactions involving tritium.

It references [this article](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.102501), “First Observation of Ground State Dineutron Decay: 16Be”.

Comment: This sounds more like a "nucleus" without a proton than two neutrons that actually "merge" in any sense.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the nuclear force has a potential curve that looks similar to the Van Der Waal forces. Notice how the potential goes up exponentially when nucleon separation is approaching zero.

[image: potential]

So even if neutrons are neutral and there is no Coulomb repulsion, you will have to overcome the nuclear force for merging two neutrons, which is extremely difficult to do.

Comment: Yes, but **how difficult** ?  :-) .  We only get stellar fusion (and later on, neutron stars) because gravity overcomes various repulsive fields.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It’s not gravity that overcomes repulsion to allow fusion, but pressure. The pressure may be caused by gravity, but its force is exerted on the fusing atoms via electromagnetism.

Comment: @MikeScott  Interesting -- certainly gravity is what causes the initial pressure and density.  Can you provide some references for E-M forces taking over (before the 2 Nuclear forces come into play